# Problems running app on iOS 5.1.1 with Xcode 4.3.2

Tags: ios, xcode

When I try to run the app on my iPad 2, I get the following message:

"No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS
version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to
run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination."

First, I checked my provisioning portal to make sure my device was properly provisioned and it shows a development certificate, a device id and an app ID. My profile shows that all of those were successfully generated and that the status is "Active".Since my device contains the most recent version of iOS, I can't figure out why the message is telling me the version isn't recent enough.  Do I need a different version of Xcode to get around this problem?

thnx

Answer (score 0):

In organizer, select provisioning profiles in the top left corner, click the refresh button in the bottom right corner. You should be prompted to enter some creds. You should see the profile created for your product in the list.

Once you complete that step, select your iPad in the list of devices and make sure that "use for development" has been selected.

(also, when you say "latest", you mean 5.1.1 right?)